# Tablelayout shrink column till wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am working a simple UI with two labels and two values.
[image]

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="9999" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            tools:text="12345" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Label 2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

In this case it is working as expected but if we change value 1 to a large number. 
[image]

Value 2 and label 2 are also wrapping with value 1. My expectation is wrapping of value 1 is fine and value 2 and label 2 should not wrap. Any way to do that? Can we stop shrinking of column 2 to the wrap content?

Comment: go for layout weight with each cell in row that would keep columns width fix.

Comment: Weight will be fixed. Suppose I have given 50/50, value 1 will start wrapping  at 50 % of the screen even right side empty space is available.

Comment: Yes you are correct value1 will wrap at 50% but value 2 and label2 would not wrap in this case. Shall we know what all constraint you have so that solution can be give accordingly

Comment: If value 1 is small, both should be on 50/50. If value 2 starts getting bigger than 50% ,value 2 should start shifting to right and that shifting should stop when it reaches right edge.

Comment: Then instead of weight you can go for `maxWidth` attribute with each cell it well make value to shift upto that width. but problem here would be  if both values are small it will look like your first image.